# Vuedraggable in nuxt 2 is not able to load sortable

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm running vuedraggable in nuxt 2 and I'm getting following errors.

> TypeError: this._sortable is undefined

These errors are only seen when cache is cleared and after I've generated the static site. I don't see this error while on development. Also this error occurs mostly when site is throttled.

I'm guessing sortable.js is not yet loaded when it is accessed by draggable in the case when error occurs.